# Remove "this question still needs 4 more votes from other users to close"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

Remove

> "this question still needs 4 more votes from other users to close"

At 3000 rep we probably know how it works :) )

Given that you can already see how many people voted to close a question "close(2)", this message seems a little redundant. I understand that some 3000 reppers might not know about the 5 votes to close a question thing, but I think the vast majority of us do and don't need a little popup to remind us. :D

Comment: Funnily enough, some people believe the exact opposite. I.e that at 3k rep people *don't* understand closing & need *more* help/guidance - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26305/why-dont-stack-overflow-users-still-know-how-to-close-questions-appropriately (admittedly, the issues raised here are more about close reasons than the actual mechanics of closing).

Comment: @alconja, I'd vote that answer

Answer (score 11):

I like these popups, as it provides confirmation that the submission actually worked.

Contrast this to what happens when you flag a post: when one flags for moderator attention, you get the popup "thanks, we'll take a look at it!", but if flagging as offensive or spam, you get *absolutely no feedback whatsoever* that the flag request was received.

Comment: You can see if the number next to close incremented or not. I would have no problem with a confirmation box **that closed itself after 2 seconds** :D

Comment: @Crazy: yep, that would be just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Let's replace it with:

**You're a closing hero, keep up the good work!**